# (I've always known) Which sentence is correct

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I don't know which sentence is grammtically correct

1.I've always known that he's a good person

2. I've always known that he has been a good person
3. I've always known that he was a good person

Just to be more specific that person is still a good person

Comment: All correct. Last sentence focuses on the knowledge (that he is good) in the past. Second sentence seems to imply that the person is no longer good. First sentence implies that the knowledge (that he is good) extends to the present.

Comment: (2) is not idiomatic.